Почему в сочетании "невидимые в темноте ступеньки" слово "невидимые" является отглагольным прилагательным, а не причастием?
На грамоте есть три правила про отглагольные прилагательные и причастия (https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/russkij-yazyk-kratkij-teoreticheskij-kurs-dlya-shkolnikov/prichastiya-i-otglagolnye-prilagatelnye), но ни одно из них не объясняет этот случай:

Причастия обозначают временный признак предмета, связанный с его участием (активным или пассивным) в действии, а прилагательные обозначают постоянный признак предмета (например, ‘возникший в результате осуществления действия’, ‘способный участвовать в действии’), ср.:

Она была воспитана в строгих правилах (=Ее воспитали в строгих правилах) — причастие;
Она была воспитанна, образованна (=Она была воспитанная, образованная).

Слово в полной форме с суффиксом -н-(-нн-), -ен-(-енн)- является отглагольным прилагательным, если оно образовано от глагола НСВ и не имеет зависимых слов, и является причастием, если образовано от глагола СВ и/или имеет зависимые слова, ср.:

некошеные луга (прилагательное),
не кошенные косой луга (причастие, т.к. есть зависимое слово),
скошенные луга (причастие, т.к. СВ).

Поскольку страдательные причастия настоящего времени могут быть только у переходных глаголов НСВ, слова с суффиксами -им-, -ем- являются прилагательными, если они образованы от глагола СВ или непереходного глагола:

непромокаемые сапоги (прилагательное, т.к. глагол промокать в значении ‘пропускать воду’ непереходный),
непобедимая армия (прилагательное, т.к. глагол победить СВ).
